# How to change text arrangement on page

Tags: formatting, pdftex, page-breaking, minipage, printing

Currently I'm using pdflatex to print content on page with width of 6 in and height of 9 in. 
It's printing in standard print orientation as mentioned in the diagram below "Current Printing format". Now to overcome some restriction, we need to print text in alignment with vertical line as mentioned in the diagram below "Required Printing Format". [image]

Can you please suggest, if there there is any package to achieve same?

Comment: Have a look at the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package. It has a landscape option and allows fine control over the page dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lscape` package:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[1]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, Text orientation is working perfectly. Can you please suggest how can we change header and footer orientation in alignment with the text? I'm using exam class \firstpageheader 
\runningheader 
\firstpagefooter  
\runningfooter

Comment: @PawanMude: I would recommend you post a separate question specfically for that and provide a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.