# text arrangement with one landscape page in between

Tags: landscape

Here is an simple example ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207210/how-to-change-text-arrangement-on-page)) ---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[1]
\end{landscape}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

In the output, more than half of the page 2 is empty and then comes a landscape page with some text in it and some more text afterwards. Is there some way to fill the blank space on page 2 with the text after landscape page?

In my original tex file, I fill the landscape page with figure and there is a lot of text before and after it.

Comment: Is it just the figure on the landscape page? If so, maybe rotating the figure would work instead?

Comment: No, I have six subfigures on it. These looks pretty with landscape page. Previously I had portrait mode too, but was ugly.

Comment: That's fine. It is still a single `figure` even if it has `subfigure`s as content. I just meant that it can be treated as a single object not exceeding a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it is basically one or more figures for the landscape page, the best option may be to rotate the figure or figures rather than switch to `landscape` mode. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: rotating figures]

Obviously, it is fine if the figure contains sub-figures. It doesn't matter what the contents of the `figure` is. What matters for this purpose is just that a `figure` never exceeds a page.

Comment: I must say, it looks great using a clean way. However, I am using it in my thesis (odd-even page). The caption are on the left of left side page, I would prefer to have them inside (i.e. towards binding side; caption on right on left page and caption on left on right page). Can I achieve that ? I tried `counterclockwise`and `figuresleft` option in rotating package but didn't work out.

Comment: it was `figuresright`option, which worked out. But probably, this will change the behaviour for all. No?